# Confusing 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

**Why my solution isn't working?**

It's an exercise for practicing 2D-Arrays, and apparently I've failed in undeerstanding them.
Input is to create a method which finds the biggest hourglass-shaped number of integers in an Array[][]. Size of an array will always be 6x6, thus for loops are x<4 and y<4, also integer values will be from -9 to 9, that's why my result variable starts with -256 (if i started with 0, array full of negative values wouldnt work)

> Sample input

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0
```

> That is the Hourglass-shape resulting in output

```
2 4 4
  2
1 2 4
```

> Sample Output

```
19
```

> My wrong output

```
13
```

> Here's the method:

public class Solution {
        public static int biggestHourglass(int[][] buffer){

```
        int result = -256; 
        int currentSize = 0;

        for (int x=0; x<4; x++){
            for (int y=0; y<4; y++){
                currentSize = (buffer[x][y+2] + buffer[x+1][y+2] + buffer[x+2][y+2]
                                        + buffer[x+1][y+1]
                         + buffer[x][y] + buffer[x+1][y] + buffer[x+2][y]);
                if (currentSize > result) { result = currentSize;}
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

> Then my biggestHourglass() method is used in main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[][] = new int[6][6];
    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 6; j++){
            arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Solution.biggestHourglass(arr));
}
}
```

My resulst doesn't match expected, and I don't know what I've made wrong. Please don't be rude, I'm still learning. Thanks!

Comment: You should specify what "biggest hourglass-shaped number of integers" means.

Comment: Look at sample imput, if you look at top left corner of this 2D array, '1's create something like hourglass shape, 1 1 1 on top, then 1 in the middle and 1 1 1 on bottom, that's a hourglass shape what I need to find, I'll try to explain it better in my question, thanks for feedback

Comment: But that's quite a loose definition. If I had six 1 on the first and third rows, and I have two 1, centered on the second row, does that count (because the general shape would be similar). Can I have more than 3 rows? What should they contain to count as a "hourglass-shaped".

Comment: No, I have to find a shape built of 7 integers, 3 on top, 1 in between and 3 on bottom. It's an easy newbie quest, I wouldn't even know how to make a method for the example you came with : o it would be hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Solution {
    public static int biggestHourglass(int[][] buffer){

        int result = -256; 
        int currentSize = 0;

        for (int x=0; x<4; x++){
            for (int y=0; y<4; y++){
                currentSize = (buffer[x+2][y] + buffer[x+2][y+1] + buffer[x+2][y+2]
                                        + buffer[x+1][y+1]
                         + buffer[x][y] + buffer[x][y+1] + buffer[x][y+2]);
                if (currentSize > result) { result = currentSize;}
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I haven't checked that, but looks like you messed x and y axis.

so basically you took:

```
[x][_][x]
[x][x][x]
[x][_][x]
```

shape instead of:

```
[x][x][x]
[_][x][_]
[x][x][x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
currentSize = (buffer[x][y] + buffer[x][y+1] + buffer[x][y+2]
                                    + buffer[x+1][y+1]
                     + buffer[x+2][y] + buffer[x+2][y+1] + buffer[x+2][y+2]);
            if (currentSize > result) { result = currentSize;}
```

*Size calculation shall be as above as you are going to add

(0,0) + (0,1) + (0,2)

```
  + (1,1) +
```

(2,0) + (2,1) + (2,2)

in your first iteration and so on*

Comment: Thank you so much!